# Vertical Label in Report Viewer

Tags: .net, reportviewer

I was wondering, is it possible to create a vertical textbox in a .net RDLC report ?

If so, how ?

Thanks

Edit : The property WritingMode works fine, but I want the label to be rotated the other way around. Is this possible ?

Comment: I am afraid i think in rdlc label not exist.

Comment: I really meant TextBox. I named it label because it's not a value I take from a database but a static value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

on the textBox property, there is a WRITINGMODE property, set it to "tb-rl" - which stands for From Top to Bottom, Right to Left.

Comment: thanks! but I only have the options vertical and horizontal. (reportviewer 2010 in vs2010. local report) am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

Check my point.

.On the textbox property set WritingMode to "tb-rl" for vertical And "lr-tb" for horizental.
Its almost same as given by other person.

Hope you get your solution and mark my answer and point me.

Answer (score 0):

In Visual Studio 2017 you just need to select the T extBox's desired and in Properties -> WrittingMode you can choose Default, Horizontal, Vertical and Rotate 270.

Hope it worked :)